# Obtaining the IP address of my gateway/router in ITS local network/subnet

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have a local network in which all devices in this network have static and known IP addresses. This network can get an outside connection through a client-router device acting as a gateway, provided that this router is connected to *another* network.

I need to know the IP address of the router in the "*another*"  network. I already know its address on the local network.

Currently, I can use a REST API built into this router to obtain this, but I would like to know if there is a way (ideally via python script but command line will do too), to obtain the IP address of any arbitrary router performing the described role (not all routers offer the REST API functionality).

I used tracepath to track the hops to , say, google.com , but the IP address that I get on the second hop (the router) is the one on the local network , not the one I need.

To illustrate further:

-Let's say my building wifi has SSID "building-wifi"

-Let's say my local network has three devices, the router on 10.66.171.1, PC1 on 10.66.171.2 and  PC2 on 10.66.171.3

-Now let's connect the router to "building-wifi". It now has a 192.168.1.45 IP address, DHCP-assigned.

-PC1 (Linux) needs a way to obtain that IP address.

If I do `tracepath -n google.com` I get

```
1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  10.66.171.1                                          0.736ms 
 1:  10.66.171.1                                          0.666ms 
 2:  192.168.1.1                                           2.532ms 
 3:  50.232.132.88                                         5.709ms 
etc
```

Any ideas on how to obtain 192.168.1.45 automatically?

Comment: This is more a networking question than a programming question. So probably more suitable over at [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com). Anyway, the easiest way is to "ask" an external host what it sees your address as. That will be the router's public IP. There are sites such as [this](http://whatsmyrouterip.com/) that are set up for that. You can probably write a script to automatically query a server like that.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but the public IP address is not what I'm after. I want to know the IP address of a LAN router connected to another LAN router, not to the public internet. I had thought of a similar approach to what you suggest, namely, using a reverse traceroute server such as [this](https://research.cs.washington.edu/networking/astronomy/reverse-traceroute.html) , but it seems to end at the public IP address and cannot go into the LAN (NAT traversal). But thanks again !